# simple Java script background image is not working

Tags: javascript

```
window.onload = function(){
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('a.jpg')";
}
```

a.jpg is in the same forlder.

but

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

works fine!

whats going wrong?

Comment: your code is working fine.

Comment: Solved : the image path is not relative to javascript file. It is relative to the html document!   strange but it worked! Don't know why javascript is designed this way!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
document.body.style.background = 'url("a.jpg")';
```

this way you apply to the **body** a **background** style property. Similar as you would do with a CSS declaration.
See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

Or, more similar to your code

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(a.jpg)";
```

**without** the single quotes.
See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

If still doesn't work then it is the path to the image that's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function(){
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(a.jpg)";
}
```

fiddle:[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/67FbC/1/)